# How to parse data from GET request in POSTMAN

Tags: api, soapui, postman, web-api-testing

[image]Can someone help me understand how to correctly reference and parse the data from a GET request in POSTMAN?

I am sending a GET request to get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "merchantId": "abcs",
        "productId": "173d-214h4-8192j-123a",
        "points": 500,
        "amount": 250
    },
    {
        "merchantId": "abcs",
        "productId": "h738-1728d-73900a-1r72",
        "points": 1000,
        "amount": 888
    },
    {
        "merchantId": "abcs",
        "productId": "7y8s-9927v-yhs40-73a8",
        "points": 2000,
        "amount": 1200
    },
    {
        "merchantId": "abcs",
        "productId": "384j-is781-9si13-927s",
        "points": 5000,
        "amount": 2599
    }
]
```

My Post request looks like this:

```
"productId": "{{productId}}",
"amount": {{amount}},
"currency": "USD",
"points": {{points}},
"last4": "9321",
"email": "{{email}}"
```

Only the first set of data from the GET response is parsed for this for some reason --- cURL for this :

```
"productId": "173d-214h4-8192j-123a",
"amount": 250,
"currency": "USD",
"points": 500,
"last4": "9321",
"email": "XXX-XXX@gmail.com",
```

I am not sure how to change the data and parse anything other than this.

Here is the cURL request

curl -X POST \
   https://www.sdefyil.us/essd/points \
   -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
   -H 'content-type: application/json' \
   -H 'postman-token: e1b1e16e-27381-b9c7-146b-f66da8249942' \
   -d '{
    "productId": "173d-214h4-8192j-123a",
    "amount": 250,
    "currency": "USD",
    "points": 500,
    "last4": "9321",
    "email": "XXX-XXX@gmail.com",
    "threeDS": {
        "type": "S",
        "version": "100",
        "data": "eyJhbGciOiJSU0ExXzUiLCJraWQiOiJBTlVCRDJ2Wk9hUU1mN09MbGRRNDYzZUx0QUVMRWVxT2hWYUs0NG1YeTZJPSIsInR5cCI6IkpPU0UiLCJ"
    }
}'

Comment: Can you post your cURL command and a screenshot of your Postman request? This is very rarely an issue with Postman, your API is probably failing somewhere.

Comment: I have added the cURL command to the original question

Comment: What is your use case?